# Solve the differential equation $(D^2+4)y=\sin 2x$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Solve the differential equation $(D^2+4)y=\sin 2x$

My solution goes like this:

> We first try calculating the solution of the differential equation $(D^2+4)y=0.$ The roots of the equation $x^2+4=0$ are $\pm 2i.$ So, the complementary function is $y_1=c_1e^{2i}+c_2e^{-2i}.$ Now, we  proceed to find the particular integral of the differential equation $(D^2+4)y=\sin2x.$ We denote the particular by  $y_p=\frac{1}{D^2+4}\sin  2x.$ Now, we know  that $\frac{1}{f(D^2)}\sin  ax=\frac{1}{f(-a^2)}\sin  ax.$ But, in this case we  observe, $f(D)=D^+4=0$ and $a=2$ so, $f(-a^2)=0.$ So, this formula is not applicable here. Hence, we assume $\frac{1}{D^2+4}\sin  2x=X$ and $\frac{1}{D^2+4}\cos  2x=Y.$ Now, $X+iY=\frac{1}{D^2+4}(\sin 2x+i\cos2x)=\frac{1}{D^2+4}e^{2ix}.$ We know that, $\frac{1}{f(D)}e^{ax}X=e^{ax}\frac{1}{f(D+a)}X,$ where X is any  function of $x.$ Now, we return to our original problem. We have, $$X+iY=e^{2ix}\frac{1}{(D+2i)^2+4}(1)=e^{2ix}\frac{1}{D^2-4+4iD+4}(1)=e^{2ix}\frac{1}{D^2+4iD}(1)=\frac{e^{2ix}}{4iD}\frac{1}{\frac{D}{4i}+1}(1)=\frac{e^{2ix}}{4iD}(\frac{D}{4i}+1)^{-1}(1)=\frac{e^{2ix}}{4iD}(1-\frac{D}{4i}+\frac{D^2}{-16}-...)(1)=\frac{e^{2ix}}{4iD}(1)=\frac{xe^{2ix}}{4i}=\frac{x}{4i}(\cos2x+i\sin2x)=\frac x4\sin 2x+i\frac x4\cos 2x.$$ Comparing the real and imaginary part, we find, $$X=\frac{1}{D^2+4}\sin  2x=\frac x4\sin 2x$$ and $$Y=\frac{1}{D^2+4}\cos  2x=i\frac x4\cos 2x.$$ But, $X=y_p=\frac{1}{D^2+4}\sin  2x=\frac x4\sin 2x.$ Now, the general solution of the given differential equation is the sum of the complementary function and the particular integral $y_p$ and is equal to $$y_1+y_p=c_1e^{2i}+c_2e^{-2i}+\frac x4\sin 2x,$$ where $c_1,c_2$ are two arbitary constant.

I am perplexed because, the method I applied to  find the particular integral $y_p$ is completely based on my ideas. I never found this sort of  process of evaluation with regards to differential operators as most book (maybe) does this evaluation of the particular  integral with a Taylor Series expansion. But, if we proceed to solve this particular integral with Taylor Series expansion, I feel the calculation effort increases tremendously. I feel my method of equating the real and imaginary parts simplifies down the calculation in an optimal way. I need a validation for my "newly discovered" ( *maybe the method I used is a standard/known one, but  I never had this in my cognizance previously* ) method and solution.

Comment: Hmm... given that $$\frac{1}{D^2+4}=\frac{1}{4}\sum_{n=0}^\infty 2^{-n}\cos\left(\frac{\pi n}{2}\right)D^n,$$
based on [the series expansion for $\frac{1}{x^3+4}$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=1%2F%28x%5E2%2B4%29+power+series), and that $$D^n \sin 2x=2^n \sin \left(2x+\frac{\pi n}{2}\right),$$ we should find $$y=\frac{1}{4}\sum_{n=0}^\infty \cos\left(\frac{\pi n}{2}\right)\sin\left(2x+\frac{\pi n}{2}\right),$$ however this absolutely diverges almost everywhere. So you're right about the Taylor series approach, and I can't wrap my head around why.